# Why date is not pasting in correct format when use excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, date

**Scenario**

I have some labels that shows dates as below dd-mmm-yy format

[image]

I paste these dates to my excel sheet by calling below function

```
Public Function enterObjectsValue(uiObject As Object)

    If TypeOf uiObject Is MSForms.Label Then
         Cells(DeviceSheetRow, headerColumn).value = uiObject.Caption
    End If

End Function
```

The format of excel cells I set as general. `DeviceSheetRow` and `headerColumn` are row and column number variables.

**Problem**

The problem is the pasting of date values are not consistent. Sometimes, it will add exactly as seen in the labels such as 08-Oct-18. But sometimes, it will paste as 10/08/18 (Date and month opposite way). Computer date format set as mm-dd-yy format. Anyone knows why is this happening and how should I prevent this?

Comment: Dates are numbers in Excel. You are using the `Caption` property, that holds a string type. But sometimes that string is read as a number and it pastes it as `dd/mm/yy` format. Sometimes not, and then it pastes it as you wish. My suggestion: paste all captions as date values, but change the format of the cell where you are pasting the dates. Change cell format with `Cells(DeviceSheetRow, headerColumn).NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yy"` or other formar according to your needs.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns May I know how can I paste captions as date values? I only knows changing cell format as the way you mentioned which is by using `.NumberFormat` property.

Comment: Exactly as I said in my last comment. Change the cell format

Comment: oh okay...so you are saying that change cell format and then paste the code? Like this

`Public Function enterObjectsValue(uiObject As Object)`
    `If TypeOf uiObject Is MSForms.Label Then`
        `Cells(DeviceSheetRow, headerColumn).NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yy"`
         `Cells(DeviceSheetRow, headerColumn).value = uiObject.Caption`
    `End If`
`End Function`

Comment: Try to combine that with `Cells(DeviceSheetRow, headerColumn).value = CDate(uiObject.Caption).` [More info about Cdate](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdate.php)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thank you. It seems working correctly. I will monitor further